# MVC 3 DropDownList displays multiple values on Edit page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-select

I'm using an enum to populate my DropDownList that works fine with a List and Create views but my Edit view loads duplicate values in the DropDownList. The duplicate values are only the selected value for the property meaning, if Rented was the value saved in the DB the DropDownList would show Rented selected, Available, and another Rented in the list. What I need to know is how to load a DropDownList that selects the value previously stored in the DB for the PropertyStatus enum without any duplicates?

Controler:

```
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Property property = db.Properties.Find(id);

        ViewBag.PropertyStatus = SetViewBagPropertyStatus();
        return View(property);
    }

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetViewBagPropertyStatus()
    {
        IEnumerable<ePropStatus> values = 
            Enum.GetValues(typeof(ePropStatus)).Cast<ePropStatus>();

            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
             from value in values
             select new SelectListItem
             {
                 Text = value.ToString(),
                 Value = value.ToString()
             };
            return items; 
    }
```

Model:

```
    public enum ePropStatus
    {
        Available ,
        Rented
    }

    public partial class Property
    {
         public int PropertyId { get; set; }
         public string PropName { get; set; }
         public string Address { get; set; }
         public string City { get; set; }
         public string State { get; set; }
         public string ZipCode { get; set; }
         public int SqFeet { get; set; }
         public int Bedrooms { get; set; }
         public int Bathrooms { get; set; }
         public int Garage { get; set; }
         public string Notes { get; set; }
         public ePropStatus PropertyStatus { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("PropertyStatus", Model.PropertyStatus.ToString())
```

Comment: try using this in your controller: `return items.Distinct();`

Comment: Adding Distinct had not effect. I'm still getting duplicate select text values in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyStatus, ViewBag.PropertyStatus)
```

**Edit :::** Alternately try this

**Controler:**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Property property = db.Properties.Find(id);

    ViewBag.PropertyStatusList = SetViewBagPropertyStatus(property.PropertyStatus);
    return View(property);
}

private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SetViewBagPropertyStatus(string selectedValue = "")
{
    IEnumerable<ePropStatus> values = 
        Enum.GetValues(typeof(ePropStatus)).Cast<ePropStatus>();

        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items =
         from value in values
         select new SelectListItem
         {
             Text = value.ToString(),
             Value = value.ToString(),
             Selected = (selectedValue == value.ToString())
         };
        return items; 
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("PropertyStatus", ViewBag.PropertyStatusList)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work I'm getting Model.Property has no applicable method DropDownListFor but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.

Comment: I had already tried using @Html.DropDownList("PropertyStatus", ViewBag.PropertyStatusList) but it still returns that same exception.

Comment: Right now we are using "DropDownList" instead of "DropDownListFor" so how can that exception occurs?

Comment: I'm not sure why it was returning the same exception with this line of code  @Html.DropDownList("PropertyStatus", ViewBag.PropertyStatusList).

Comment: I tried your other example posted above, and I still am getting this exception: Compiler Error Message: CS1973: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<PropertyManagementMVC3.Models.Property>' has no applicable method named 'DropDownListFor' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: '@model PropertyManagementMVC3.Models.Property


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropertyStatus)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PropertyStatus, ViewBag.PropertyStatusList)
          
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.temp)
        </div>'

Comment: @Shawn, in this mark up you are using "DropDownListFor" and the problem is occurring

Comment: Yes I changed everything to your example above except I had to add the ToString() at the end of your parameter list for PropertyStatus. SetViewBagPropertyStatus.... 'SetViewBagPropertyStatus(property.PropertyStatus.ToString());'. The code form the view I copied and pasted into the post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19422/discussion-between-shawn-and-kundan-singh-chouhan)

Comment: Thanks again Kundan. The solution to this problem was to add this to the view: '@Html.DropDownList("PropertyStatus", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.PropertyStatusList)'